# Once I create wind, all physics in the scene stops working. Why?

Tags: physics

I am making a flag animation.

I brought in an image as plane and turned it into a cloth.

I pinned left most vertex as the pole.

Then I ALT + A to see how the animation would look. It worked fine.

But once I create force field - wind. All physics stops let alone wind blowing.

[image]

Comment: What is the Strength option of the force field? It could be so high that the flag won't be able to stop.

Comment: I found out I needed to wait for more than 10 seconds to see it working.